# JQuery - How to check if a span has a class and add a class if one doesnt exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help with some jquery code to check if a span has a class. If it doesn't have a class then add class customtab to this span. How can I do this in jquery?

Here's example html menu.

```html
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="user_menu_link" href="#"><span class="menu1">Menu Item 1</span></a><li>
        <li><a class="user_menu_link" href="#"><span class="menu2">Menu Item 2</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="user_menu_link" href="#"><span class="menu3">Menu Item 3</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="user_menu_link" href="#"><span class="menu4">Menu Item 4</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Menu Item 5</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here's the code I'm trying to use but doesn't work.

```js
$('ul a').each(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('class') == "") {
    $(this).find('span').addClass("customtab");
  }
});
```

I was able to use this code to make it work.

```js
$('ul a').each(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('class') === undefined) {
    $(this).find('span').addClass("customtab");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What class are you checking for and when, e.g. on click, when the page is loaded, hover, etc.

To check, there is a `hasClass` method:

```
// $(this) being the element you are checking for the class
// this could be inside a click function for example
if ($(this).hasClass('menu1')) {
    $(this).addClass('customtab');
}
```

**Update**

To check for no `class` attribute, try this:

```
if ($(this).attr('class') === undefined) {
    $(this).addClass('customtab');
}
```

If you don't know what `$(this)` is then you can find the element by looping through the elements:

```
$('li a.user_menu_link span').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('class') === undefined) {
        $(this).addClass('customtab');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/992g694f/

Fiddle with fixed HTML - http://jsfiddle.net/992g694f/1/

**Update 2**

```
$('ul a').each(function() { 
    if($(this).attr('class') === undefined){    
        $(this).find('span').addClass("customtab"); 
    }
});
```

Comment: I want to check if the span has a class. In the html you will see the Menu Item 5 has no span class. I want the code to find the menu item that has no class and add class customtab. I only want it to add the class to the menu item that doesnt have a class.

Comment: I tried the above but it added the class customtab to all the spans

Comment: @James30263 are you sure? I created a fiddle and it seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/992g694f/. For some reason there's an extra `li`, there must be a typo in the html but I can't see it.

Comment: @James30263 found the typo, the first `li` hasn't been closed properly.

Comment: yep, it's adding it to all the spans. I changed the html above because the menu item 5 doesn't have a class. I was able to use this to fix it.  $('ul a').each(function() {
   if($(this).attr('class') === undefined){
    $(this).find('span').addClass("customtab");
   }
 });

Comment: ah, I see, just noticed that the last `a` doesn't have the `user_menu_link` class, I was concentrating on the `span` too much, removing the class from my selector in the loop should fix it.

Comment: I added correct code above. Post the same code and I will give you credit for it. Without your code I wouldn't have solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
$(".menu a span").filter(function() {
    return this.className == '';
}).addClass('customtab');
```